# Why isn't this rectangle rotating?

Tags: jquery, css-animations

This red rectangle is supposed to animate, but it doesn't. I looked for a typo, but still don't know what's wrong.  http://jsfiddle.net/gcgtcwqv/1/

jQuery:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    class: 'logo',
    text: 'Cake Baby'
    }).appendTo($("#cakeHook"));
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-animation-name: CB; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: CB;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation: CB 5s; 
    -webkit-animation: CB 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes CB {
    0%  {left: 0px, transform: rotate(0deg);}
    25%  {left: 20px, transform: rotate (10deg);}
    75%  {left: 10px, transform: rotate (15deg);}
    100% {left: 5px, transform: rotate(0deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes CB {
    0%  {left: 0px, transform: rotate(0deg);}
    25%  {left: 20px, transform: rotate (10deg);}
    75%  {left: 10px, transform: rotate (15deg);}
    100% {left: 5px, transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo mistake here:

```
0%  {left: 0px, -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
              ^
```

Here should be `;` instead of `,`

Here is Working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gcgtcwqv/3/)

Removed extra space also See updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gcgtcwqv/5/)

> Note: OP was giving *left* property in animation, so i have also added
>   **position:absolute**.

Comment: Not much rotating going on :/

Comment: Ah, it's got extra spaces between `rotate` and `(xdeg)` - http://jsfiddle.net/gcgtcwqv/5/. Probably also worth mentioning how you added `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Use `;` as @manwal suggested and `left` needs positioning so you can use `margin-left` instead and remove extra space between rotate as it is a function.

```
@keyframes CB {
    0%{margin-left:0px;transform: rotate(0deg);}
    25%{margin-left:20px;transform: rotate(10deg);} 
    75%{margin-left:10px;transform: rotate(15deg);}
    100%{margin-left:5px;transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/gcgtcwqv/6/)

```
@keyframes CB {
    0%{left:0px;transform: rotate(0deg);}
    25%{left:20px;transform: rotate(10deg);}
    75%{left:10px;transform: rotate(15deg);}
    100%{left:5px;transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
.logo{
    position:relative;
    ....
}
```

[Demo with left position](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/gcgtcwqv/8/)